# Moduli interpretation and Ogg's notation for the cusps on modular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

In Ogg's paper "rational points on certain elliptic modular curves", the author says, using Ogg's notation for cusps,
that for fiexed $d$, if $(y, N) = d$, then for any $x$ satisfying $(x, y, N) = 1$, the cusps of the form
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) $$
are conjugate, and hence for $d = 1, 2$, these are rational.

But I don't know the moduli interpretation for cusps in $X_1(N)$ for $N$ composite.

I know that the cusps
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ y \end{array} \right) $$
are corresponding to the Neron $N$-gon with a $\Gamma_1(N)$-structure $(1, a) \in \mu_N \times \mathbb{Z}/N$,
and the cusps
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$
are $1$-gon.

How about other cusps?

Comment: This is explained in Diamond-Im, Modular forms and modular curves, section 9.3. You should get the Galois action from that.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you. I checked that, but couldn't find it. In 9.3.4, the authors say that the singular locus of the Tate curve with $1$-gon, resp., $p$-gon  gives $\infty$, resp., $0$ without proof. I want to know its proof, and the case of composite levels.

Comment: In the beginning of section 9.3 you can find the discussion over $\mathbb{C}$. Then they go on to define the moduli space $\mathcal{X}_1(N)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ and you can work out the Galois action from the moduli interpretation.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault In it, it seems for me that the authors show only the bijectivity, and not the holomorphy.
In the 3rd paragraph of section 9.3, the authors says that the bijection is holomorphic, but I couldn't find its proof.

Comment: This is an important point. For $Y_1(N)$ here is the idea: $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$ has algebraic Weierstrass equation $y^2 = x^3 - g_4(\tau) x - g_6(\tau)$ where $g_4$ and $g_6$ are $\textit{holomorphic}$ functions of $\tau$. For details see the notes by Loeffler https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/modular_curves.pdf, Prop 3.13. Similar for $X_1(N)$, using the Tate curve $y^2+xy = x^3 + a_4(q) x + a_6(q)$. When $q \to 0$ this converges to a $1$-gon (see Diamond-Im, 9.2). For other cusps, use level structures on the Tate curve over $\mathbb{C}((q^{1/N}))$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you. But it seems that the convergences do not work well. The curve $E(q)$ you mention is the 1-gon when $q = 0$. But why does this mean, on $X_1(N)$, that $E(q)$ (with an approapriate structure) $ \in X_1(N)(\mathbb{C})$ converges to the 1-gon? What topology should I consider?

Comment: The Tate curve provides a description of the complex points of the universal generalised curve $E_1(N) \to X_1(N)$ near the cusps (the cusps correspond to level structures on the Tate curve, see Loeffler, Prop 4.6). The map $(\tau,z) \mapsto (X(u,q),Y(u,q))$ (notations in Prop 4.5) shows that $E_1(N)(\mathbb{C})$ is a Néron polygon above the cusps, and that $X_1(N)(\mathbb{C})$ is what you think. Unfortunately I don't have the time to give a lecture on this so I suggest you read the references I gave, and work them out.

Comment: Maybe also this introduction: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~pbruin/moduli.pdf

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I’ll try it. Much appriciated for your kindness!